# D3 force layout approach towards repetitious links

Tags: d3.js

My question is about when d3.layout.force().start() is being called, not when one appends the links to the SVG.
I need to know if the algorithm removes repetitious links or considers all of them when calculating the layout.

I am asking because I need to find a way to apply weights to links between nodes on certain circumstances (when they are members of the same cluster), and all I can think of is to apply links between those nodes that satisfy this condition.

It is good to also mention that there are different link/relationships types in my context, so node A and B might have a link because they have a relationship type I as well as another of type II. Therefore the strength of the gravity between these two nodes should be more compared to those that do not have the latter relationship.

With all this being said, is there also another way of appending weights to each link, so that I can dynamically modify that attribute instead of adding more links?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can have multiple links between the same nodes, but those will show up as separate links. You probably want to use a custom attribute that you use to set the link strength and how the link is shown.

Comment: Correct, and those links as they show up (when they are appended) are not my concern.

Again, I am first concerned about the way that the algorithm calculates the layout, esp. the distance between nodes with and without links in between them.

About the second part, do you have any idea how that custom attribute could be thought of, because appending links (lines) between nodes has nothing to do with the distance between nodes.

Comment: The attribute can be anything you like. You would then reference it when setting [`.linkDistance()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkDistance) or `.linkStrength()`.

Comment: But that is set once you initiate the layout, and is the same value for all nodes. One cannot have a custom linkStrength based on the number of links between nodes I assume; right?

Comment: You can pass a function as argument that will be evaluated for each link. In that, you can reference an attribute that determines the strength/distance of that particular link.

Comment: Oh both great and confusing!

So something like force.linkStrength(someFunction), and then inside that function I shall return values 0.5 or 1 based on some criterion.

The problem is that this criterion is an attribute of each link, so I need to have access the link between two nodes to decide, and that link is generated once start() is called, i.e. not yet!

Comment: The links are what you pass to `force.links()`.

Comment: Just to clarify the terminology, I'm sure @LarsKotthoff is talking about a custom **property** on the elements of the array that is passed to `force.links()`, not a custom **attribute** on the svg elements.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @CoolBlue -- yes, I mean a custom property/attribute on the data you're using, not on the generated elements.

Comment: Correct. Now the problem is very simple: if you have a link between A and B with a weight of 3 and a link between A and C with a weight of 2, will the former be nearer to one another without any manipulation?

My understanding is that they won't, because once .start() is called, only the number of links between the nodes count as the decision criterion.

Now if you consider they same example with many nodes between links (possibly representing different relationship), each having different weights, this problem becomes more sophisticated.

Comment: Your suggestion was to set the input of .linkStrength() a function, but that function acts on what to decide the strength value? That I am still confused. Sorry if this looks naive to you.

My understanding is that you believe the criterion should be the weight property of each link, but I am not sure if that is true.

Comment: Surely you can answer those questioned by experimenting?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I will try it based on your answers.